# Codeigniter Login page wont login! Bcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Dwightwatson's CodeIgniter Bcrypt library for my own login and registration page as I try and learn CodeIgniter. I have got the registration page working and it inserts all of the users data correctly. The issue is upon login. Please find the library here for reference https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt

To store the hash into the DB I have the following code in my `user_model.php` file.

```
public function add_user()
    {
        $passunhash = $this->input->post('password');
        $passhash = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($passunhash);

   $this->db->set('password', $passhash);
    $this->db->insert('users');
}
```

To decrypt the password for login stages I attempt to use

```
$this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $stored_hash)
```

But it throws back an error saying "undefined value $stored_hash". I have set bcrypt to autoload through the config!

**UPDATE - All files as requested.**

user_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function login($email,$password)
    {
        $this->db->where("email",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);

        $query=$this->db->get("users");
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                //add all data to session
                $newdata = array(
                        'user_id'       => $rows->id,
                        'user_name'     => $rows->username,
                        'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                        'logged_in'     => TRUE,
                   );
            }
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function add_user()
    {
        $passunhash = $this->input->post('password');
        $passhash = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($passunhash);

$this->db->set('password', $passhash);
$this->db->insert('users');
    }
}
?>
```

User.php (controller)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
        {
            $this->welcome();
        }
        else{
            $data['title']= 'Home';
            $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
            $this->load->view("registration_view", $data);
            $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
        }
    }
    public function welcome()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Welcome';
        $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('pass');
    $passwordhashed = $this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $stored_hash);

        $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$passwordhashed);
        if($result) $this->welcome();
        else        $this->index();
    }
    public function thank()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Thank';
        $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('thank_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
    }
    public function registration()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('security');
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pin', 'Pin', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->user_model->add_user();
            $this->thank();
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $newdata = array(
        'user_id'   =>'',
        'user_name'  =>'',
        'user_email'     => '',
        'logged_in' => FALSE,
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }
}
?>
```

Bcrypt.php (library file)

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Portable PHP password hashing framework.
 *
 * Version 0.3 / adapted for CodeIgniter by Dwight Watson.
 * http://www.github.com/studiousapp/codeigniter-bcrypt
 *
 * Written by Solar Designer <solar at openwall.com> in 2004-2006 and placed in
 * the public domain.  Revised in subsequent years, still public domain.
 *
 * There's absolutely no warranty.
 *
 * The homepage URL for this framework is:
 *
 *  http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
 *
 * Please be sure to update the Version line if you edit this file in any way.
 * It is suggested that you leave the main version number intact, but indicate
 * your project name (after the slash) and add your own revision information.
 *
 * Please do not change the "private" password hashing method implemented in
 * here, thereby making your hashes incompatible.  However, if you must, please
 * change the hash type identifier (the "$P$") to something different.
 *
 * Obviously, since this code is in the public domain, the above are not
 * requirements (there can be none), but merely suggestions.
 **/
class Bcrypt {
    /**
     * Privates
     */
    private $_itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    private $_random_state;

    /**
     * Options
     */
    private $_iteration_count = 8;
    private $_portable_hashes = FALSE;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array
     */
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        if (count($params) > 0)
        {
            $this->initialize($params);
        }
        if ($this->_iteration_count < 4 || $this->_iteration_count > 31)
            $this->_iteration_count = 8;
        $this->_random_state = microtime();
        if (function_exists('getmypid'))
            $this->_random_state .= getmypid();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize preferences
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array
     * @return  void
     */
    private function initialize($params = array())
    {
        if (count($params) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($params as $key => $value)
            {
                if (isset($this->{'_' . $key}))
                {
                    $this->{'_' . $key} = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected function get_random_bytes($count)
    {
        $output = '';
        if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
            ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
            $output = fread($fh, $count);
            fclose($fh);
        }
        if (strlen($output) < $count) {
            $output = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
                $this->_random_state =
                    md5(microtime() . $this->_random_state);
                $output .=
                    pack('H*', md5($this->_random_state));
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
        }
        return $output;
    }
    protected function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $value = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $this->_itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->_itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->_itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            $output .= $this->_itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);
        return $output;
    }
    protected function gensalt_private($input)
    {
        $output = '$P$';
        $output .= $this->_itoa64[min($this->_iteration_count +
            ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);
        return $output;
    }
    protected function crypt_private($password, $setting)
    {
        $output = '*0';
        if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
            $output = '*1';
        $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
        # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
        if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$')
            return $output;
        $count_log2 = strpos($this->_itoa64, $setting[3]);
        if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
            return $output;
        $count = 1 << $count_log2;
        $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
        if (strlen($salt) != 8)
            return $output;
        # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
        # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
        # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
        # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
        # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
        # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
            $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
            do {
                $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
            } while (--$count);
        } else {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
            do {
                $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
            } while (--$count);
        }
        $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
        $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);
        return $output;
    }
    protected function gensalt_extended($input)
    {
        $count_log2 = min($this->_iteration_count + 8, 24);
        # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
        # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
        $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;
        $output = '_';
        $output .= $this->_itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->_itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->_itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->_itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);
        return $output;
    }
    protected function gensalt_blowfish($input)
    {
        # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
        # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
        # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
        # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
        # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
        # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
        # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
        # of entropy.
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $output = '$2a$';
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->_iteration_count / 10);
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->_iteration_count % 10);
        $output .= '$';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
            $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
            if ($i >= 16) {
                $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
                break;
            }
            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;
            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);
        return $output;
    }
    public function hash_password($password)
    {
        $random = '';
        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->_portable_hashes) {
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 60)
                return $hash;
        }
        if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->_portable_hashes) {
            if (strlen($random) < 3)
                $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 20)
                return $hash;
        }
        if (strlen($random) < 6)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
        $hash =
            $this->crypt_private($password,
            $this->gensalt_private($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 34)
            return $hash;
        # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
        # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
        # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
        return '*';
    }
    public function check_password($password, $stored_hash)
    {
        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
        if ($hash[0] == '*')
            $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);
        return $hash == $stored_hash;
    }
}
/* End of file bcrypt.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/bcrypt.php */
```

Comment: Can you show the code around the check_password line

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn Yes that's inside the bcrypt.php Library file i'll add that now.

Comment: `public function check_password($password, $stored_hash)
 {
  $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
  if ($hash[0] == '*')
   $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);
  return $hash == $stored_hash;
 }`

Comment: No the code where $this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $stored_hash) is in, because the undefined value means that that value doesn't exists

Comment: Yes @MitchellOlsthoorn that is the code I've given you. Its inside the library file and then autoloaded into all pages with CodeIgniter library autoload part in config

Comment: But where does the $stored_hash variabele come from that goes into the check function?

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn How about now give it a check.

Comment: @Drew I included all that was requested in the OP

Comment: @JBower The $stored_hash isn't defined. You first have to get it from the database

Comment: I can't give you a more detailed answer because the question is marked as duplicate, so I can't formulate an answer.

Comment: But the error is in your User.php file login function